# search for specific characters within column and then create different columns from it

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I have  param_Value column that have different values. I need to extract these values and create columns for all of them.

```
  |PARAM_NAME |param_Value |
    __________|____________
  |Step 4     |  SP:0.09   |
  |Procedure  |  MAX:125   |
  |Step 4     |  SP:Ambient|
  |(null)     |  +/-:N/A   |
  |Steam      |  SP:2      |
  |Step 3     |  MIN:0     |
  |Step 4     |  RDPHN427B |
  |Testing De |  N/A       |
```

I only want columns with:           And give them names:

```
  SP:                SET_POINT_VALUE,
  MAX:               MAX_LIMIT,
  MIN:               MIN_LIMIT,
  +/-:               UPPER_LOWER_LIMIT
```

So what I have so far is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW PROCESS_STEPS 
("PARAM_NAME", "SET_POINT_VALUE", "UPPER_LOWER_LIMIT", "MAX_VALUE", "MIN_VALUE")
AS
SELECT PARAM_NAME,        
       REGEXP_LIKE("param_Value", 'SP:')   SET_POINT_VALUE,
       REGEXP_LIKE("param_Value", '+/-:') UPPER_LOWER_LIMIT,
       REGEXP_LIKE("param_Value", 'MAX:')  MAX_VALUE,
       REGEXP_LIKE("param_Value", 'MIN:')  MIN_VALUE
FROM PROCESS_STEPS 
;
```

Comment: Building a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) might help people help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with TSQL and MySQL, but this ought to do what I think you're looking for.  If it doesn't exactly, it should at least point you in the right direction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW PROCESS_STEPS 
    ("PARAM_NAME", "SET_POINT_VALUE", "UPPER_LOWER_LIMIT", "MAX_VALUE", "MIN_VALUE")
AS
SELECT PARAM_NAME  
        , CASE WHEN "param_Value" LIKE 'SP:%'
            THEN SUBSTR("param_Value", INSTR("param_Value", ':')+1)
            ELSE Null
        END SET_POINT_VALUE
        , CASE WHEN "param_Value" LIKE '+/-:%'
            THEN SUBSTR("param_Value", INSTR("param_Value", ':')+1)
            ELSE Null
        END UPPER_LOWER_LIMIT
        , CASE WHEN "param_Value" LIKE 'MAX:%'
            THEN SUBSTR("param_Value", INSTR("param_Value", ':')+1)
            ELSE Null
        END MAX_VALUE
        , CASE WHEN "param_Value" LIKE 'MIN:%'
            THEN SUBSTR("param_Value", INSTR("param_Value", ':')+1)
            ELSE Null
        END MIN_VALUE
    FROM PROCESS_STEPS
;
```

The basic concept here is identifying the information you want via LIKE, then using SUBSTR and INSTR to extract it.  While LIKE is normally something to stay away from, since there's no leading % in your case, it's [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), and thus probably not a total efficiency sink.

Really, though, I have to ask you to question why you're laying out your data like this - substring operations are slow in any language, and a DB is no exception.  Why not use another column for your limit type?  Why not lay it out in the view you're currently looking at?

Comment: Yes. I am going to recreate that view and have those columns.